# Make checkbox read only if opportunity probability is 95% or more

Tags: salesforce, custom-fields

Is there a way to make checkbox read only if opportunity probability is 95% or more?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a before update trigger to see if the checkbox value has changed and the probability was previously >= 95%. Then add a field error and reject the change.

Answer (score 0):

If its an Enterprise Edition you can use rerender="{!methodname}" & in that method you can check the % value n accordingly you can make it show/hide

If its a Professional Edition, I dont think its possible but you can avoid making changes in checkbox by using validation: check whether % value is below 95 if so then throw error else update